# Dynamic 2d rendering in a 3d world

Tags: xna, drawing

Ok, so I'm working with my first serious experience in XNA. Here's my current task: Download a file. From that file parse a list of "shapes." Each "shape" contains a list of points. These points are the vertexes of lines to be drawn on a map. In fact, it is a county map of the entire United States, so the number of "shapes" is not trivial. We need to be able to zoom in and out of this map, so it needs to be a 2d rendering in 3d space. I want to know what the best strategy for this would be.

I've tried simply using DrawUserIndexedPrimitives, but the draw function takes way too long to process this.

So then I thought I'd try drawing to a series of RenderTarget2D's in LoadContent, and just saving those textures for drawing in the Draw function. But so far all I can seem to get is a series of purple boxes.

EDIT:

Here's my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace First
{
class FirstShape : DrawableGameComponent
{
    const int kSizeMultiplier = 10;

    public FirstShape(string inFilePath, Game inGame) : base(inGame)
    {
        DrawOrder = 1000;
        mFile = inFilePath;
    }



    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        mSpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        FirstMemoryStream stream = FirstMemoryStream.MakeSeekableStream(File.OpenRead(mFile));

        // skip headers
        stream.Seek(100, 0);

        for (int i = 0; stream.Position != stream.Length; i++)
        {
            stream.Seek(stream.Position + 12, 0);

            double minX = stream.ReadDouble();
            double minY = stream.ReadDouble();
            double maxX = stream.ReadDouble();
            double maxY = stream.ReadDouble();
            int numParts = stream.ReadInt();
            int numPoints = stream.ReadInt();

            VertexPositionColor[] points = new VertexPositionColor[numPoints];

            stream.Seek(stream.Position + (4 * numParts), 0);

            int top, bottom, left, right;

            float x2, y2;
            x2 = (float)stream.ReadDouble();
            y2 = (float)stream.ReadDouble();

            Vector2 projectedPoint = Vertex(x2, y2);

            left = right = (int)Math.Round(projectedPoint.X * kSizeMultiplier);
            top = bottom = (int)Math.Round(maxY - (projectedPoint.Y * kSizeMultiplier));

            points[0].Position.X = left;
            points[0].Position.Y = top;

            for (int j = 1; j < points.Length; j++)
            {
                float x1 = x2;
                float y1 = y2;

                x2 = (float)stream.ReadDouble();
                y2 = (float)stream.ReadDouble();

                Vector2 p1 = Vertex(x1, y1);
                Vector2 p2 = Vertex(x2, y2);

                p1.X *= kSizeMultiplier;
                p1.Y *= kSizeMultiplier;
                p2.X *= kSizeMultiplier;
                p2.Y *= kSizeMultiplier;

                points[j].Position.X = (int)Math.Round(p2.X);
                points[j].Position.Y = (int)Math.Round(maxY - p2.Y);

                if (points[j].Position.X < left)
                    left = (int)points[j].Position.X;
                if (points[j].Position.X > right)
                    right = (int)points[j].Position.X;
                if (points[j].Position.Y < top)
                    top = (int)points[j].Position.Y;
                if (points[j].Position.Y > bottom)
                    bottom = (int)points[j].Position.Y;
            }

            if (mTopLeft.X == 0 || mTopLeft.X > left)
                mTopLeft.X = left;
            if (mTopLeft.Y == 0 || mTopLeft.Y > top)
                mTopLeft.Y = top;

            for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++)
            {
                points[j].Color = Color;
            }

            int width = (right - left) + 1;
            int height = (bottom - top) + 1;

            mTextures.Add(new FirstImage(GraphicsDevice, width, height, new Vector2(left, top)));

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(mTextures.Last());
            GraphicsDevice.Indices = new IndexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, IndexElementSize.SixteenBits, points.Length, BufferUsage.None);
            GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration, points.Length, BufferUsage.None));

            BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
            basicEffect.LightingEnabled = false;
            basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

            foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, 0, points.Length, 0, points.Length - 1);
            }
        }

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

        stream.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < mTextures.Count; i++)
        {
            mTextures[i].Position -= mTopLeft;
        }

    }



    public override void Draw(GameTime inTime)
    {
        mSpriteBatch.Begin();

        for(int i = 0; i < mTextures.Count; i++)
        {
            mSpriteBatch.Draw(mTextures[i], mTextures[i].Position, Color.White);
        }

        mSpriteBatch.End();
    }



    private Vector2 Vertex(float inX, float inY)
    {
       return FirstProjector.Project(new Vector2(inX, inY));
    }



    public Color Color { get; set; }



    private string mFile;
    private List<FirstImage> mTextures = new List<FirstImage>();

    private SpriteBatch mSpriteBatch;
    private Vector2 mTopLeft = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    private Vector2 mBottomRight = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
}



class FirstImage : RenderTarget2D
{
    public FirstImage(GraphicsDevice inDevice, int inWidth, int inHeight, Vector2 inPosition) : base(inDevice, inWidth, inHeight, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None)
    {
        Position = inPosition;
    }
    public Vector2 Position {get; set;}
}
```

}

Comment: The pre-rendering idea sounds like a good solution. Can you show your code? You can also introduce tree-like data structures and perform visibility checks before drawing something. Btw, which part of your scene id 3D?

Comment: See my code added to my post. To answer your question, there's nothing in the scene itself that is 3d, but I want to be able to use the camera as though it were 3d so I can zoom in and out to particular counties.

Comment: Are `FirstImage` and `FirstMemoryStream` classes of your own?

Comment: They are. You can see the definition of FirstImage at the bottom of the code. FirstMemoryStream is just a MemoryStream that makes for easier reads.

Comment: Well, I just got a clue. I added GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent); just above the EffectPass loop. Nothing was drawn. Then I changed it to GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Wheat) and the boxes came back, but in Wheat color. But the LineStrip is clearly not being drawn.

Comment: What matrices are set in the effect? You should adapt the viewport to the texture's dimensions. By the way, I would partition the scene into a grid and draw a texture for each grid cell. Not a texture for a number of lines.

Comment: Well, I got it to work by using DrawUserIndexedPrimitives instead. The problem is I can't get it to draw in high enough a resolution... I guess I'm going to have to forego the use of XNA